Needle dependency injection via build phase exception
I get a exception when trying to build my iOS application with Needle dependency injection in Xcode, i have the following command in the build phase run script:
export SOURCEKIT_LOGGING=0 && /opt/homebrew/bin/needle generate "$SRCROOT/App/Infrastructure/DependencyInjection/Generated/GeneratedCode.swift" "$SRCROOT/App/Infrastructure/DependencyInjection/Components/AppComponent.swift"

I get this error:
 Unknown error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “AppComponent.swift” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/mennospijker/code/iOS/Kenteken Scanner/Kenteken Scanner/Infrastructure/DependencyInjection/Components/AppComponent.swift, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003d900f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

The file exists and the path is correct, the permissions for the file are -rw-rw-rw-@
What could be the cause for this? I can't find any information about this issue. The mac i work on is a Macbook Air M3, for reference.
